# unable to add a fragment tag inside a relative layout

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments

I want to add a  tag inside a RelativeLayout of an Activity. But i am getting rendering errors.

[image: fragment tag]

Any help on how to solve?

Edit: Adding the stacktrace of the crash

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.chandranichatterjee.mapapp/com.example.chandranichatterjee.myapplicationloc.MapsActivityNew}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2583)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1499)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5767)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:412)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2204)
        at com.example.chandranichatterjee.myapplicationloc.MapsActivityNew.onCreate(MapsActivityNew.java:24)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6322)}
```

Comment: It's more helpful to post the code, not using a picture with the code.
Is the problem still existing?

Comment: The code is right there in the picture.Yes the problem is still existing

Comment: Yes, but I mean it is way more helpful to give the code as text and mark as code, so users can eventually try it out. When you give the code in a picture, less people will be willing to put effort into it with retyping all the code from an image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by @Nazariy Moshenskiy , I needed to add `android:name` attribute to the `<fragment>` tag.

This is how my layout looked like(in case someone encounters the same problem in future).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    map:cameraZoom="2"

    tools:context=".MapsActivityNew" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to add `android:name="com.example.myapp.YourFragmentHere"` inside your fragment to define a `Fragment` class if you are going to use `<fragment>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

As your error message says:

> A `<fragment>` tag allows a layout file to dynamically include different layouts at runtime. At layout editing time the specific layout to be used is not known. You can choose which layout you would like previewed while editing the layout.

It doesn't know what the Fragment should show, but it can be ignored, since the result in the end does know it. You can't just have such a general preview.

**Edit:**

Most common mistakes from experience with inflating a fragment are:

using:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
```

instead of:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
```

and having `meta-data` tag outside the `application` in the manifest file.

Comment: It cannot be ignored as the application crashes on setContentView method.

Comment: If your app crashes at some point, you need to add the error output and the corresponding code, so we can help you

Comment: Edited the question,added the stacktrace

Comment: Good, since I can't trace the error in your code I have to shoot freely at the possible issues, I added the most common mistakes by inflating a fragment in my answer

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `android:name="com.example.YourFragmentHere` inside your `fragment` tag to define a Fragment class. like this

```
<fragment  
android:id="@+id/fragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"  
android:layout_height="match_parent"  
android:name="com.example.YourFragmentHere"  
/>
```